# I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and after the system installation is complete, I get this prompt

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, reboot, restart

`Please remove the installation medium, then press reboot`

But there is no way to reboot other than holding down the power button.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDDUA.jpg]

Comment: hmmm seems like a cryptic error.... Have you tried removing the installation medium?

Comment: It doesn't say "press reboot". It either says "reboot", in which case you should be able to do Ctrl + Alt + Del, or "press ENTER to reboot".

Answer (score 1):

A poweroff following by a cold start works the same as a reboot after the Ubuntu installation has been finished and you get the `Please remove the installation medium, then reboot.` message. Just make sure that the installation medium is removed before starting the computer again or it will boot from the Ubuntu installation medium again instead of booting normally from what is installed on the hard drive.

1. Shut down the computer by holding down the power button.
2. Remove the installation medium (USB or DVD). A DVD can be removed by manually ejecting the CD/DVD tray if you temporarily stop the boot process by entering the BIOS/UEFI setup utility, eject the CD/DVD tray, remove the DVD, close the CD/DVD tray, and then exit the BIOS/UEFI setup utility without saving any changes.
3. Wait for one minute and then cold start the computer by pushing the power button.
4. Now your new Ubuntu installation will be able to boot normally.